# Error in promise catch does not trigger global error handler

Tags: javascript

Why does an error thrown in a promise reject/catch method not trigger the global error handler?
How can a global error handler that includes these be created?
In my app the global error handler logs the error.

```
function doPromise() {
    return Promise.reject()
}

window.addEventListener('error', function (e) { console.log('Global handler ' + e.message) })

doPromise()
 .then()
 .catch(e => {
    console.log('Promise catch')
    throw new Error('Promise catch error')  // Does not trigger global error handler
  })
    
throw new Error('Core error')  // To prove global error handler is working
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an error, but [`Unhandled Rejection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event):

> The unhandledrejection event is sent to the global scope of a script when a JavaScript Promise that has no rejection handler is rejected

Working version of the code:

```js
function doPromise() {
    return Promise.reject()
}

window.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    console.log('Global handler ' + e.message)
})
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', event=>{
    console.log('Unhandled rejection', event)
}
);

doPromise().then().catch(e=>{
    console.log('Promise catch')
    throw new Error('Promise catch error')
    // Does not trigger global error handler
}
)

throw new Error('Core error')
// To prove global error handler is working
```

Comment: Thanks Alex.
The argument to unhandledrejection event is a PromiseRejectionEvent, not an Error.  The error object (if there is one) is available as event.reason.

Comment: Right, well, this is just an example of handling this type of error.